# Swiftui - Firebase Storage upload multiple images and have one progress bar

Tags: firebase, mvvm, swiftui, progress-bar, firebase-storage

My view has a for loop that calls uploadImage for each selectedImage.

My progress bar takes a binding of uploadAmount, but it seems like upload amount is constantly being updated improperly because of the other images being uploaded. This is causing a weird behavior with the progress bar.

How would I have one Upload Amount for all images being submitted to firebase storage ?

```
func uploadImage(image:Data,fileName:Document, side: String = "") {
        self.progressBar = true
        self.hideProgressBar = false
        
        let storage = Storage.storage()
       let uploadTask = storage.reference().child("docs/\(fileName)\(side)").putData(image, metadata: nil) {_ , error in
            storage.reference().child("docs/\(fileName)\(side)").downloadURL { (url,error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    return
                  }
              
                self.saveDownloadUrl(url: downloadURL, fileName: fileName)
            }
        }
        uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            self.uploadAmount = snapshot.progress!.fractionCompleted
            if (self.uploadAmount == 1.00) {
                self.hideProgressBar = true
                self.progressBar = false
                self.uploadAmount = 0.0000
                print("progress done")
            }
  
        }
    }
```

View function

```
    func submitImages() {
        if selected.count >= 1 {
            var data = NSData()
            var iteration: Int = 0
            for i in selected {
                iteration += 1
                data = i.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)! as NSData
                loanApplicationService.uploadImage(image: data as Data, fileName: Document.PayStubs, side: String(iteration))
            }
        }
    }
```

Progress bar

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
     var uploadProgress: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Uploading...")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        ProgressView("", value: uploadProgress ,total: 1.00)
        .foregroundColor(.green)
        .accentColor(Color(red: 68 / 255, green: 159 / 255, blue: 100 / 255))
        .animation(.spring())
        .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 4, anchor: .center)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely going to require a little more code/complexity than something that is easily answered here. You'd have to store the progress of *each* image and then come up with an algorithm to reconcile all of the progress numbers to try and show an overall amount.

Comment: This is what I was thinking and seen online that NSProgress might have this behavior already if I add a child progress to the parent. Where I get lost is how im going to track each individual request from the for loop and create a unique NSProgress for it.